# Highlight a sub string from middle of the string with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to make the middle part of my number string bold.

I have a number string :

```
$nmbr="55113741659856";
```

I want to highlight 4 numbers in the middle ,from the 6th position

```
......7416......
```

and replace them with bold letters

```
<b>7416</b>
```

My currunt code is failing to do what I want

```
 $nmbr="55113741659856";
 preg_replace("/d+([0-9]{4,6})/i","<b>$1</b>",$nmbr);
```

Your Help is much appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to highlight 4 numbers in the middle ,from the 6th position

I'd do:

```
$nmbr="55113741659856";
preg_replace("/^(\d{5})(\d{4})/","$1<b>$2</b>",$nmbr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `\d+`.

```
preg_replace("/\d+([0-9]{4,6})/i","<b>$1</b>",$nmbr);
```

The reason is:

```
\d     Find a digit
```

And you missed the `\` here.